# How to traverse a two-dimensional list?

Tags: c++, list

I have an assignment to "simulate a music machine on radio station". I have to use lists. So i decided to use a two dimensional list, so that it was possible to find the needed track faster. The structure is something like this: [image] Pardon my paint skills.
And the structs declaration is like this.

```
struct TrackNode
{ 
   int PlayLimit;
   std::string TrackName;
   TrackNode *NextTrack; 

};

struct ArtistNode
{
    std::string ArtistName;
    ArtistNode *NextArtist;
    TrackNode *NextTrack; 
};
```

What i don't understand is how to traverse such list. How to display artist name with track name when it is stored in artist node? How to know when i arrive at the next artist?
I don't need code, just basic principle. And please don't tell me to use something other, because i have to use multidimensional lists.

Comment: What does it mean for an `ArtistNode` to have a `NextArtist` *and* a `NextTrack`?

Comment: the data structure doesn't make sense to me either. can you elaborate on why do you want it that way? what is a "music machine" and what is its task you're trying to solve?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth each node in the linked list of `ArtistNode` (linked by `NextArtist`) has a linked list of `TrackNode`. The picture is missing the link lines directly between `ArtistNode` objects, and the last `TrackNode` of a track list should *not* have a link to the next `ArtistNode`. (at least that was my take on this, ymmv).

Comment: @WhozCraig so last track shouldn't be linked to the next artist? So i get to next artist only from artist nodes?

Comment: Exactly. Are you trying to build a *playist* ? if so, a secondary data structure is likely going to do what you need. The one you present here is more like a "library" list. A play list would be a list of pointers referring to nodes in your "library". It isn't too far a stretch to see that may be what you're trying to do.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you for explaining. I think i got it all now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly like this:

```
ArtistNode* first_artist;
for( ArtistNode* artist = first_artist; artist != 0; artist = artist->NextArtist ){
    for( TrackNode* track = artist->NextTrack; track != 0; track = track->NextTrack ){
        cout << artist->ArtistName << ' ' << track->TrackName << endl;
    }
}
```

You have two dimension, so you you need a loop to walk your artist list, and for each artist, a nested loop to walk that artist's tracks.

Comment: If it helps at all, the last sentence may also be: "You need a loop to walk your artist list, and for each artist, a nested loop to walk that artist's tracks."

Comment: Thanks, much better than mine, copied :-)